# Update raw query is not working in django

Tags: django

**Here i passing value by post request from form and and want to update only notes field from TestcaseCache table pk is id of TestcaseCache table**

```
def saveReviewTestcase(request,self,test_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print test_id
        input_notes=request.POST.get('textarea')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE TestcaseCache SET  id= test_id  WHERE notes = %s", [self.input_notes])
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print row
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out your question you want to update the notes where some id,

**Instead**

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE TestcaseCache SET  id= test_id  WHERE notes = %s", [self.input_notes])
```

**Use This**

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE TestcaseCache SET  notes= %s  WHERE id = %s", [self.input_notes, test_id])
```